# Excel formula to find a number within a range of numbers and return a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First time writing one of these, so I will try and explain what I'm trying to do in an understandable manner.

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet to track when a premium bond wins, and have it return the date that the winning premium bond was purchased. Because premium bonds cannot be purchased singularly, when you buy them your bond numbers are given to you a range (eg: 111AA111111- 111AA111210).
As this is the data they provide, I've set my spreadsheet up with purchase date in column A, first number of the range in column B, and last number of the range in column C.

Sample image of the sheet with example bond ranges and purchase date:

[image]

Now on a separate sheet I've listed the wins, with win date in A, winning bond number in B, and prize amount in C. In D or E I would like to somehow get it to then give me from the first sheet the date of purchase that winning bond was from.

Sample image of the sheet with winning bond numbers and month they won:

[image]

I've done a lot of googling and found *similar* threads to do this, but none of them have been quite what I want and I've not yet been able to work out how to tweak  them into doing it. These have used index and sumproduct, but I'm yet to get it to work.

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated. If this doesn't make sense let me know and I'll try and explain it better.

Comment: So instead of sumproduct(), consider vlookup() or match() to drive the index. But Is Apr 22 meant to be the purchase date as that is not matched in the example dates you show...

Comment: So Apr 22 is used on the second image as an example sheet of wins. So that date is the month that particular bond number came up as a winner.

Comment: If you are on excel-365 the `XLOOKUP()` would be perfect function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, like this:

[image]

```
INDEX($B$3:$B$5,MATCH(C9,$C$3:$C$5,1))
```

Not added a constraint to limit to the upper value, but you could.

Comment: That has worked a treat. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty much the same than @SolarMike's answer but based on a diferent point of view.

If the pattern is always like **111AA111111** where 1 is a numeric value and AA is a text value **and unique** then you can extract the text part from each id using function MID and search for it with INDEX and MATCH:

[image]

Formula is:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$3;MATCH("*"&MID(B9;4;2)&"*";$B$1:$B$3;0))
```

But for this to work each AA must be unique.

Comment: Unfortunately the 'AA' isn't always unique. I've got a couple of bonds where purchased same day as such so both have 'AA' but the number ranges are different. So one might be 111AA100000-111AA100100 and the other is 111AA100500- 111AA100600.