# MySQL Query to show table payment and its transaction details by id_customer

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables

```
tbl_customer:
id | name
1  | Ahmad
2  | Taha
3  | Amir

tbl_payment
id | payment
1  | food
2  | drink

tbl_transaction
id | id_customer | id_payment | date
1  | 1           | 1          | 2022-08-20
2  | 2           | 1          | 2022-08-21
3  | 2           | 2          | 2022-08-21
```

And i want to show the payment transaction details based on id_customer.
Expected result for Ahmad:

```
id_payment | payment | date
1          | food    | 2022-08-20
2          | drink   | null
```

Expected result for Taha:

```
id_payment | payment | date
1          | food    | 2022-08-21
2          | drink   | 2022-08-21
```

Expected result for Amir:

```
id_payment | payment | date
1          | food    | null
2          | drink   | null
```

How to do that?

Comment: have you tried vlookup() or index() with match()? lots of examples applying them on here.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I try this: 
`SELECT p.*, t.date
FROM tbl_payment AS p
LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction AS t ON p.id = t.id_payment
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer AS c ON c.id = t.id_customer
WHERE c.id = 1`

Comment: @SolarMike can you give an example of its use?

Comment: Yes, lots of examples of hlookup(), vlookup(), index() with match and even xlookup() which is in office 365 can be found on here. See this as one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73635642/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike sorry, I'm asking about mysql query, not excel.  can these functions be applied to mysql queries?